# My docker containers are named differently than the containers of my coworkers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

unfortunately I am no expert on docker and the person who set it up on this project is long gone.

From my knowledge, container names should be in snakecase. On my machine the containers are in kebabcase however.
I end up with this container `foobar-mysql-1` instead of `foobar_mysql_1` and I have all kinds of problems and I'm wondering if this is the root cause.

I am on Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed5707e.

I have checked the `docker-compose.yml` but there isn't any container naming set.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do? Or how I could investigate this?

Also a different question: How would I "start over" with everything docker related? I have been running it on this machine for about 2 years now and its the first time that updating my local db inside the docker container has failed. So I am wondering if setting up the whole project would be a good idea. Including recreating the volumes...

Comment: I pruned containers and volumes and tried rebuilding everything but it keeps naming the things with - instead of _

Comment: tried to restore backups from before I started this docker adventure but apparently /lib/var/ was not part of the backup... So I can't go back

Comment: container name will be (by default) `folder-of-compose-project_service-name_replica-number` the underscores are only but at theses places. It doesnt change how the folder or your service was named.

Comment: I am now naming the containers manually in docker-compose: `container_name: "foobar_mysql_1"`.

Comment: For the reason for the different naming see the linked question. But since these names are automatically managed by `docker-compose` they should not make any difference. If you have other issues with your `docker` setup you should ask specific questions describing those issues.